# Find rolling maximum per group

Tags: r, dplyr

Ok im working with time series data. I am using dplyr to group by per day. Then within each day group, I wish to find the rolling maximum. I need to know if that particular row value is the maximum of the day, if it is, then I guess I need to print the current maximum until the next maximum is encountered.

My procedure so far is below:

```
day.group <- new.df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(day = format(Date, "%d")) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(RunID = data.table::rleid(day)) %>%
  group_by(RunID) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(max = runMax(Close , 1))    #Borrow run max from TTR package
  #dplyr::mutate(day.high = ifelse(Close > max,1, 0))
```

This is close... but to find the rolling maximum. I need to always find the maximum during the day at any given point. I am using runMax with a rolling lookback of 1 day. This is not useful... because even if i set the look back to the maximum rows of that day I would be comparing last row to first and rest = NA.

Essentially I need to compare the current row to all previous rows from first row... to last on per row basis.

excel is like this:

```
=MAX($F$2:F3)
```

Finding max of all on rolling basis and $F$2 setting first row for comparison. This will always print the current maximum on each row until a new max is encountered. I need to place that in my dplyr code.

Dummy data:

```
  Close day RunID   output
114.19  1   1   
114.31  1   1   114.31
114.22  1   1   114.31
114.09  1   1   114.31
114.28  1   1   114.31
114.19  1   1   114.31
114.25  1   1   114.31
114.22  1   1   114.31
114.25  1   1   114.31
114.13  1   1   114.31
114.03  1   1   114.31
114.28  1   1   114.31
114.19  1   1   114.31
114.25  1   1   114.31
114.22  1   1   114.31
114.34  1   1   114.34
114.19  1   1   114.34
114.19  1   1   114.34
114.16  1   1   114.34
114 1   1   114.34
114.06  1   1   114.34
114 1   1   114.34
114.06  1   1   114.34
114.25  1   1   114.34
114.16  1   1   114.34
114.31  1   1   114.34
114.44  1   1   114.44
114.53  1   1   114.53
114.59  1   1   114.59
114.75  1   1   114.75
114.75  1   1   114.75
114.75  1   1   114.75
114.91  1   1   114.91
114.72  2   2   114.91
114.64  2   2   114.91
114.59  2   2   114.91
114.52  2   2   114.91
```

Comment: What does the desired result look like? `cummax` may be all you need, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: let me try... output attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
read.csv(text="Close,day,RunID,output
114.75,1,1,114.75
114.75,1,1,114.75
114.75,1,1,114.75
114.91,1,1,114.91
114.72,2,2,114.91
114.64,2,2,114.91
114.59,2,2,114.91
114.52,2,2,114.91", header=T) -> data

cummax(data$Close)
```

Returns

```
114.75 114.75 114.75 114.91 114.91 114.91 114.91 114.91
```

This seems to match your output column.